# How can I test whether one empirical CDF is to the left or right of another?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, cumulative-distribution-function, boxplot

I am currently working with a box plot (shown below) that consists of two boxes per value of one of the independent variables (call it $x$). The other independent variable is indicated by the two boxes (call it $y$). The blue box represents the dependent variable (call it $z$) under the condition $y = 1$, while the red box represents $z$ under the condition $y = 2$. The bottom and top whiskers represent the 10th and 90th percentiles respectively, while the bottom and top edges of a box represent the 25th and 75th percentiles respectively. The median is marked in black.

My hypothesis is that, when $y = 1$ (blue box), the empirical CDF of $z$ is to the right of the empirical CDF of $z$ when $y = 2$ (red box) "in general" (on average or otherwise) for every value of $x$. This relationship (although not particularly strong) can be seen in the plot below. However, I am not sure how to phrase this precisely in terms of a statistical test.

One possibility that I thought of was to use a two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for each value of $x$, but I am not sure how helpful this would be. Another possibility, is that, because the data was generated in pairs, i.e., one specific value of $z$ when $y = 1$ can be matched to another specific value of $z$ when $y = 2$, then I should subtract the value of $z$ when $y = 2$ from the corresponding value of $z$ when $y = 1$, and then check that the values are always (or mostly) positive. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're interested in whether sample `y`
stochastically dominates sample `x`. If so,
you might want to look directly at ECDF plots, and do some formal tests.

Here are summaries and ECDF plots of two samples.

```
summary(x); length(x);  sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  5.067  14.628  21.012  21.807  28.297  53.943 
[1] 30        # sample size
[1] 10.56207  # sample SD

summary(y); length(y);  sd(y)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  12.81   25.30   29.27   29.25   32.56   45.47 
[1] 30
[1] 8.098928

plot(ecdf(x), col="blue", main="ECDFs", xlab="values")
lines(ecdf(y), col="brown")
```

[image]

Because the ECDF of `y` (brown) plots to the right of
the ECDF of `x` (blue), and therefore below, it seems
the values of `y` are generally larger than
values of `x`

A two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test confirms this
with a P-value below 5%. The test statistic $D$
is the maximum vertical distance between the two
ECDF plots.

```
ks.test(x,y)

        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x and y
D = 0.43333, p-value = 0.006548
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

When two samples are not of the same shape (including the same variability), a two-sample
Wilcoxon Rank Sum test, is said to be a test
of stochastic dominance (rather than of different
medians).

```
boxplot(x, y, horizontal=T, col=c("skyblue2", "wheat"))
```

[image]

```
wilcox.test(x,y)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  x and y
W = 236, p-value = 0.001292
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is not equal to 0
```

*Notes:* (1) Technically speaking, there are several
different types of 'stochastic dominance' with
somewhat different definitions. You may be interested in googling that. Perhaps start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance).

(2) The fictitious samples used in the above
discussion were sampled in R as follows:

```
set.seed(2022)
x = rgamma(30, 4, 1/5)
y = rgamma(30, 5, 1/5) + 7
```